# Running cuda on a MBP?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I'm trying to setup CUDA on a Macbook Pro, I've installed cuda with brew:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install cuda
```

Added this to my .bash_profile

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I also installed cuDNN v5.1

```
sudo mv include/cudnn.h /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/include/
sudo mv lib/libcudnn* /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib
sudo ln -s /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib/
```

I'm now trying to test it:

```
cp -r /usr/local/cuda/samples ~/cuda-samples
pushd ~/cuda-samples
make
```

but I get this error:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
clang++  -rpath /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib -framework CUDA -o clock_nvrtc clock.o  -lnvrtc
ld: framework not found CUDA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [clock_nvrtc] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/clock_nvrtc/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I have an intel graphics card and CUDA only works with nvidia....

Comment: However that is not the only error :( you have not installed the CUDA framework